# Spring Data elasticsearch hangs during client initialization

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring Data Elasticsearch. Below is my configuration

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
        .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
        .put("node.name","Onyxx")
        .put("client.transport.sniff", false)
        .build();

    Client client = new TransportClient.Builder()
        .settings(settings)
        .build()
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300)));
```

The issue is my program always hangs out when it executes the

```
Client client = new TransportClient.Builder()
            .settings(settings)
            .build()
```

What is the issue here ?

Below is the snippet from my elasticsearch.yml file

```
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: "Onyxx"
network.bind_host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. Issue was with the version mismatch of elasticSearch and the spring-data-elasticsearch jar file. My elassticsearch is at 5.x version and spring-data-elasticsearch is compatible for 2.x version.

Also I have installed the elasticsearch as a service in my ubuntu machine which was running with root permission, that's why the logs were not printing the issue.

I remove the elastic search and download it as a whole package as a zip file.